# $stmt->error throws Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following query:

```
// pagination
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ' . $table)) {
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($totalitems);

    $stmt->fetch();

    if (!isset($page)) {
        $page = (int)$page_number <= 0 ? 1 : (int)$page_number;
    }

    $limit = 4;

    if ($page > ceil($totalitems / $limit)) {
        $page = ceil($totalitems / $limit);
    }

    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

    $stmt->close();

    if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                                    FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                                    INNER JOIN ' . $table2 . ' t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                                    ' . $optional_cond . $optional_cond2 . '
                                    LIMIT ?, ?')) {
        $stmt2->bind_param('ii', $start, $limit);
        $stmt2->execute();

        $stmt2->bind_result($col1, $col2, etc...);

        while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()) {
            echo $col1 . '<br>';
        }
    } else echo "Statement failed: " . $mysqli->error . "<br>";
}
```

It's not working, so I've added an `else`:

```
else echo "Statement failed: " . $stmt2->error . "<br>";
```

But it's throwing the following notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

I can't see what's wrong with my query, what's going on?

FIX (by @Michael Berkowski - in comments):

```
else echo "Statement failed: " . $mysqli->error . "<br>";
```

Comment: Ok I see what's going on now. You have 2 conditional statements being `$optional_cond` and `$optional_cond2`,  and then you're including both variables for them in your query `' . $optional_cond . $optional_cond2 . '`. you're not checking for errors here. `$optional_cond2 = ' AND t2.zone = ' . $zone;` should read as `$optional_cond2 = ' WHERE t2.zone = ' . $zone;`

Comment: we're dealing with strings here, so both your variables need to be quoted.

Comment: i.e.: `'".$string."'` or `'$string'`

Comment: The error will be on the `$mysqli` object, not `$stmt2`. Check the output from `echo $mysqli->error`.

Comment: Right! thanks, i get this: `Statement failed: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`. Do you know what it means?

Comment: @ChazyChaz That looks like you called `fetch()` once on the previous statement, but it has additional rows left to fetch. That's typically the reason for "commands out of sync". Make sure you fetch _all_ rows from the previous statement or close it.

Comment: Yes, after fetching you can close it. Since it's an aggregate COUNT(), it should be returning just the one row, right?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to open a chat... `get_result()` is only available with the mysqlnd driver. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: You have to use `bind_result()` and `fetch()` as you did with the first statement. It's a pain.

Comment: Using `while($stmt2->fetch()) {...}` and the bound vars $column1, $column2... inside the loop. See examples at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php  You cannot use `fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Yes thanks, I got it! :)